# Calculate average number of years with TIMESTAMPDIFF

Tags: mysql, timestampdiff

I need to calculate the average number of years from my MySQL database, and I try to use TIMESTAMPDIFF

Which one gives a valid result:

```
AVG( TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, tanggal_masuk, tanggal_yudisium )/12 )
```

or

```
AVG( TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, tanggal_masuk, tanggal_yudisium ) )
```

`tanggal_masuk` and `tanggal_yudisium` columns are DATE type.

Comment: why dont you try it by yourself? There are tonssss of online tools you can try this in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how accurate you want your final result to be. Using `TIMESTAMPDIFF` with `MONTH` and dividing by 12 will give floating point results (e.g. 0.5 years) where using it with `YEAR` will only give integers (e.g. `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '2018-09-01', '2018-01-10')` is 0) where `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2018-09-01', '2018-01-10') / 12` gives -0.5833. Overall, using `MONTH` will give more accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

These statements both yields same result. It is up to you.

```
select ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2018-01-01', '2010-01-01') / 12); --Result 8

select ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '2018-01-01', '2010-01-01') )   --Result 8
```